# Keep getting "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup." dailyLimitExceededUnreg. Keep searching, can't find answer

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-drive-api

I know many other people on Stack Overflow have been running into this issue, but I can't seem to find the answer in my case.

I am trying to do a drive.files.list call for a shared drive in my organization and keep running into the 403 error listed in the title. It's strange though, because when I do calls such as drive.permission.list with the same authentication it works just fine.

I am using Node/Typescript

I am authenticating via JWT, and in it I am passing in a specific user in my organization's email to impersonate. This specific user does have access to the drive I am trying to call.

```
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env') });
import { google } from 'googleapis';
export const main = async () => {

  const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    process.env.SERVICE_ACCT_EMAIL,
    process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_KEYFILE_LOCATION,
    null,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'],
    process.env.IMPERSONATE_USER_EMAIL
  );

  jwtClient.authorize(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
  });

  const drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: jwtClient,
  });

  try {
    // try files.list
    const responseHere = await drive.files.list({
      includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
      supportsAllDrives: true,
      auth: jwtClient, // same bad result with or without this parameter
    });
    console.log(responseHere);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return;
  }
};
main();
```

Here is some of the stack trace I get back:

```
GaxiosError: Rate Limit Exceeded
    at Gaxios._request (/.../node_modules/gaxios/src/gaxios.ts:158:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async JWT.requestAsync (/.../node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:368:18)
```

When I follow one of the urls on the error response I get:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

I've confirmed lots of things the other stack overflow posts have recommended:

- Drive V3 API is enabled in GCP
- It almost seems like I get this error with api calls where the docs say authentication is optional, but not where the google api docs say it's required...
- I believe I am passing the auth parameter correctly to the drive api
- I'd prefer not to use an API key for the auth, but do it this way if possible
- My service account does have domain-wide delegation that is set up correctly (I believe)
- My GCP console doesn't show that I'm hitting any specific quota limit listed there. I suspect something is going wrong with authentication for this call
- I've seen things about getting restricted scopes verified by Google, but I'm only using this on my local machine in development at the moment so I don't believe I need this?
- I have tried doing authentication via oauth2client and seem to be getting this exact same error
- The only two users of this app have been me via oauth2 and the service account

Comment: When I follow one of the urls on the error response I get:  <--- Could you tell me please what urls exactly are returning the no authorization message?

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&supportsAllDrives=true